# Unable to access the class in lib from helper module in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am working on rails app. In the function makeRequestToAPI1 of ArticlesHelper module, I am calling the API1 class's (this class is present in lib/) method "createRequest(request). But it is giving me "NoMethodError".

articles_helper.rb

```
require '././lib/ThirdPartyLibs/api1'
require '././lib/ThirdPartyLibs/api2'

module ArticlesHelper
    include  EnumsHelper

    def makeRequestToAPI1(request)
        # here as request to API is same as the original request
        # so I am directly passing the request to the API
        response = API1.createRequest(request)
        Rails.logger.debug "makeRequestToAPI1: #{response}"
    end

    def makeRequestToAPI2(request)
        requestToAPI2 = {}
        requestToAPI2.merge!({:items => request[:items]})
        requestToAPI2.merge!({:pickup => request[:pickup]})
        requestToAPI2.merge!({:drop => request[:drop]})

        #response = API2.createRequest(requestToAPI2)
        #Rails.logger.debug "makeRequestToAPI2: #{response}"
        end
end
```

api1.rb

```
class API1 
    #class << self

    def self.createRequest(request)
        @response = {:etd => 10, :eta => 20}
    end
end
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are doing wrong. The first things are that you are not following the naming conventions of the rails. Please first clean your code. It's totally ugly code your are writing.

Comment: @Bharatsoni, can you specifically point out where I am violating the conventions. Apart from that, can you help me with answer to the question

Comment: You can refer rails guides and other blogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try adding following line to applicaion.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Comment: @paramvir Please upvote and accept answer if it helped :)